# How to code a factor variable when a value lies between two other factors either with a new column or by adding levels?

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
    id    time              x     y      pickup_dropoff
    1    2/1/2013 12:23    73    40       pickup
    1    2/1/2013 12:25    73    40.2     ping
    1    2/1/2013 12.27    73    40.5     ping
    1    2/1/2013 12:34    73    41       dropoff
    1    2/1/2013 12:35    73    41.4     ping
    1    1/1/2013 12:45   73.6   41       pickup
    1    1/1/2013 12:57   73.5   41       dropoff
    2    1/2/2013 12:54   73.6   42       ping   
    2    1/2/2013 13:00   73.45  42       pickup
    2    1/2/2013 14:00   73     42       dropoff
    2    1/2/2013 14:50   73.11  41       pickup
    2    1/2/2013 15:30   73     44       dropoff
    2    1/2/2013 16:00   73.1   41       pickup
    2    1/2/2013 18:00    74    42       dropoff
```

Thanks to the help I received in this post:
[Reshape Data partially from Wide to Long in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021088/reshape-data-partially-from-wide-to-long-in-r)

I was able reshape the data to resemble the above. I'm looking now to recode some of the factor values to show when a vehicle is in use or is cruising without being in use, This new variable would make the following assumptions:

1. if a ping is between a pickup and a dropoff the vehicle is in use
2. if a ping is between a dropoff and a pickup its out of use

I'd like the output to look like the following:

```
        id    time              x     y      pickup_dropoff     status
         1    2/1/2013 12:23    73    40       pickup           pickup
         1    2/1/2013 12:25    73    40.2     ping              inuse      
         1    2/1/2013 12.27    73    40.5     ping              inuse
         1    2/1/2013 12:34    73    41       dropoff           dropoff
         1    2/1/2013 12:35    73    41.4     ping              nouse
         1    1/1/2013 12:45   73.6   41       pickup            pickup
         1    1/1/2013 12:57   73.5   41       dropoff           dropoff
         2    1/2/2013 12:54   73.6   42       ping              unknown
         2    1/2/2013 13:00   73.45  42       pickup            pickup 
         2    1/2/2013 14:00   73     42       dropoff           dropoff
         2    1/2/2013 14:50   73.11  41       pickup            pickup
         2    1/2/2013 15:30   73     44       dropoff           dropoff
         2    1/2/2013 16:00   73.1   41       pickup            pickup 
         2    1/2/2013 18:00    74    42       dropoff           dropoff
```

I currently have pickup_dropoff coded as a factor with 3 levels.

One solution I am playing with is adding a column with the factor levels 
of 1, 2, 3, then using as.numeric to turn them into numericals and then writing a couple of if statements like the following:

```
            df$status = ifelse(df$pickup_dropoff LAYS BETWEEN 3
            and 1, df$pickup_dropoff == "inuse", df$pickup_dropoff)
```

I may be overthinking this, but I'm not sure if there is a way to say "in between" in R. Also I have to deal with another dimension "id" since I don't want a ping between two different ids to be considered in use. In any case it would be considered "unknown" as the data I am working with is incomplete.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need more levels, not in between.

Comment: that's true, I guess adding levels on a condition would be helpful. I'm wondering how to phrase an if statement to add levels , so if x factor value lays between y and x for a given id, code "in use". Not sure what the syntax would look like

Comment: pickup and dropoff - is that your Russian chauffer's name?  Your data doesn't see fine grained enough for this.  I'd expect to see a millisecond or nanosecond timestamp, because pickup, dropoff, between, and in use will all be true at discrete moments in time.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(
    status = ifelse(pickup_dropoff == "pickup", "inuse",
        ifelse(pickup_dropoff == "dropoff", "nouse", NA))
) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(status = zoo::na.locf(status, na.rm = F),
       status = ifelse(pickup_dropoff %in% c("pickup", "dropoff"), pickup_dropoff, status),
       status = ifelse(is.na(status), "unknown", status))
```

First will put in the values for pickup and dropoff that we want the new column to take after pickup and dropoff, leaving everything else as `NA`. Then we fill in the missing values using `zoo::na.locf` (grouped by ID). Lastly, we reset the values at pickup and dropoff to what we actually want.

This creates a character vector - you can of course stick a factor conversion at the end.

---

Using `plyr` or `base` instead of `dplyr`:

```
df$status = with(df, ifelse(pickup_dropoff == "pickup", "inuse",
                ifelse(pickup_dropoff == "dropoff", "nouse", NA))

## pick one
# base
df$status = ave(df$status, df$id, FUN = function(x) zoo::na.locf(x, na.rm = F))
# plyr
df = plyr::ddply(df, "id", plyr::mutate, status = zoo::na.locf(status, na.rm = F))

df$status = with(df, ifelse(pickup_dropoff %in% c("pickup", "dropoff"), pickup_dropoff, status))
df$status = with(df, ifelse(is.na(status), "unknown", status))
```

Comment: would this be possible in the plyr package? I'm running a higher version of R that won't allow me to load the dplyr package

Comment: You mean a lower version? Sure - I can try to make a quick edit.

Comment: Thanks for the point the right direction! So when I try to run the ave function on df$status I get the following error: Error in `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) : 
  replacement has length zero. Any ideas

Comment: I wasn't accounting for IDs in your data that start with a `ping`. I'll make some edits.... should be better now.

Comment: Btw, if you had shared your data with `dput()` so it was copy/pasteable I would have checked my solution. `dput(droplevels(head(df, 14)))` would share the top 14 rows of your data in a very convenient way.

Comment: understood, thanks for the help. I'll make sure moving forward to make the data shareable. I'll test this in a bit see if it goes through. Thanks!